# Filter out some properties from a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, oop, collections, filter

I have a list of objects (`MyObject`) which has 10 properties.

```
Class MyObject{
   string F1,
    string F2,
   ....
   string F10
}

 var myList = new List<MyObject> ()
```

From that mylist I have to filter out some property and get a new list of selected items depending on the input provided in a List of string.

```
var requiredFlields = new List<String> {"F1", "F2"}
```

I know this :

```
var o1 = myList.Select(a => new {  a.F1, a.F2 }).ToList();
```

but it doesn't allow me to use the requiredFields list for filtering.

Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: you can use reflection for this and filter from propertyinfo list

Comment: something like this (untested) `typeof(MyObject).GetProperties().Where(x => requiredFields.Contains(x.Name)).SelectMany(y => myList.Select(x => y.GetValue(x, null))` - have to be carefull though with what a property is and what a variable is

Comment: yes, myList is of type List<MyObject>, it contains many objects

Answer (score 0):

You can get property details from class, using `GetProperties()` function.Use it to get details of all properties.

Iterate through each property and check name of that property is present in class or not.

**Sample code:**

```
PropertyInf[] propertiesInfo = MyObject.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo item in propertiesInfo)
{
    if(requiredFields.Contains(item.Name))
        {
            //Do your operation here
        }
}
```

With the help of `PropertyInfo` you can check **name of property, type of property, GetSetMethod()**

For more details: [PropertyInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: that should be a comment and if you want it to be an answer then consider posting relevant code

Comment: its not doing what is required, requirement is to create a new list depending on the values present in requiredFlields

Comment: new list of what? New list of propertyInfo?your primary question was not acccessible `requiredField list` inside Linq, am I right? Please correct me if I am missing any thing

Comment: Output should be a new list with less properties, the properties in the new list is defined as the requiredFlields List<string>

Comment: You can store `List<PropertyInfo>` containing properties which are available in `requiredFields`, not sure about storing `properties` into list